# Most Common Memory/Resource Leak Errors

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

All good C++ programmers know how to avoid leaking memory (or resources like sockets):

1. Always use smart pointers, i. e.: `std::auto_ptr`, `boost::shared_ptr`.
2. Always be aware of ownership of object: who owns, who refers, who is responsible, etc.

But, memory leaks still happen. Point most common issues when you discovered 
a memory leak in a program, even when you used the above techniques.

**I start:**

Sometimes you forget to define a destructor of base class as virtual. So all derived classes referred by pointer to the base class which was not destroyed properly and therefore leaked.

Answer (score 5):

There are many more types of errors than just leaks. In order from worst to best:

#### Memory corruption.

Data is stored to an area where it shouldn't. This results in both the majority of security problems *and* is by far the hardest to track down.

- "Random location" corruption

  - Data is stored to a memory location that the user can control.
  - Data is stored to an array without checking the indices.
  - An object of a type derived from `X` is stored to an array element reserved for a base type of `X`, and the size of `X` is greater than the size of its base.
- Lifetime corruption

  - Data is store to a memory location after it is freed.
  - Incorrect method of freeing is used (mismatch resulting in `new`/`free`, `malloc`/`delete`)
  - `delete` or `free` is called twice on the same pointer.

#### Failure to release memory

Memory no longer in use by the program remains allocated.

- Incorrect method of freeing is used: mismatch resulting in `new[]`/`delete` instead of `new[]`/`delete[]`.
- Memory is not automatically release because of a circular reference in a reference counting scheme, such as can happen when `smart_ptr` is used in a circular data structure without attention to using `weak_ptr` for the circular link.
- Memory is not freed due to a lost pointer - the last pointer to the memory was cleared before free was called, so there is no way to release it.
- Memory is not freed due to not properly identifying when the data it contains is no longer needed. An example is a static cache used for some temporary task is never cleared out.

Answer (score 2):

Circular references are common, and they aren't solved by `std::auto_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr`
There is no substitute for (2) on your list, which is using your brain.

Comment: Unfortunately. But *never* use your brain for something that a computer can do perfectly well for you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

- Calling a virtual function like "cleanup" from within the base-class destructor.  You probably only do this once... (no more polymorphism in the destructor of the base-class)
- Not cleaning up an stl::multimap (no erasing, only inserting) and wondering why your program keeps on becoming slower.

Answer (score 1):

A mistake made by people too familiar with automatic garbage collection (through smartpointers):

```
class A { 
public:
    int avery_useful_calculation()const { return 4; } 
private:
    // class shouldn't be instantiated as an automatic variable (on stack)
    virtual ~A(){} 
};

// client code: needs a very useful calculation

int i = (new A)->avery_useful_calculation();
```

Comment: Good example of a leak... but maybe change the comment next to the private virtual constructor to say something like "class can't be instantiated **on the stack**" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am out of scope, but I had some strange errors trying to "delete" uninitialized pointers.

To "avoid" memory leakage, I use the `try {} __finally {}` structure if implemented (but I read somewhere it may be inefficient if an exception was raised in a sub-sub-call)

Comment: first of all, there is no such thing finally in `C++`, it is just microsoft ext.. You should use `std::auto_ptr` that destroyes to object when you exit scope. Actually, C++ does not need finally because it has deterministic destructors.

Comment: Thank for the information... I precised "if implemented" because it is not standard but may be usefull. By the way, I use it in Borland where there is a similar ext.