# Could you give me a real work example of memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I heard a lot of memory leak vulnerability, but I could not find a real work example of memory leak, could you provide a real work example of memory leak, maybe of some big open source project and explain the solution to me

thx.

Comment: I guess many big open source projects do have memory leaks, especially when using lots of libraries.

Comment: Firefox used to suffer from memory leak issues: http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/255389/mozilla_cracks_down_on_memory_leaks_in_firefox_addons.html and http://kb.mozillazine.org/Memory_Leak#Memory_leaks

Comment: What sort of answer do you expect: A small, extracted code sample that doesn't look "real" anymore, or a 2000-line source code file from an actual project?

Comment: Minecraft is known to slowly climb in memory usages until it crashes with an out of memory error, especially with 32bit versions of Java.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I would prefer the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot examples could be given here. Just allocate some memory and do not free it.

A good example for this would be the following:

```
char* pBuffer = new char[ 1024 ]; // or something else, dynamically allocated

// do something here

// now suppose, calling f() throws
f();

// do some other things

delete[] pBuffer;
```

When `f()` throws, if the exception is not caught, `delete[]` will never be executed. Thus, memory leak.

This is one of the best examples why smart pointers should be used.

---

Another example would be - a function, returning pointer to dynamically allocated memory. The user, often, may forget to free this memory. Something like:

char

```
char* f()
{
    return new char[ 1024 ];
}

//... 

// in some other function
char* pSomething = f();

// do some stuff here and return
```

Answer (score 4):

It's really simple actually. In your main put:

```
char* c = new char[4];
```

Then exit. That's a memory leak. Any `new` that doesn't get followed by `delete` is a leak.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1332724/1549464) has some good examples, but like my comment has said, it will be fairly hard to find a released application with a leak that an outside observer can look at and easily identify.

Comment: Right, but I don't think a lot of real world applications that have been released are going to have simple to find/understand memory leaks.

Comment: For that I guess one could google search for change logs using keywords like fixed a memory leak.

Comment: True, steve, but that doesn't make your answer any more applicable to his question.

Comment: That's not really a memory leak, since there's only one allocation, regardless of how long the program runs.

Answer (score 3):

I am screaming, cursing and yelling everyday about code like this in our (huge) legacy code base:

```
// returns raw pointer with changing conventions who's the owner...
HelpFoo* Foo::GetFoo(Bar* pBar, OtherFoo* pFoo)
{
    // all 'local' variables even those allocated on freestore declared 
    // and initialized in a large block at the beginning of the function/method
    HelpFoo *A = new HelpFoo;
    OtherHelpFoo *B, *C;
    EvenMore *D = new EvenMore;
    // and so on, these blocks can be huge...

    // a complicated spaghetti code in here, with dozens of nested 'ifs'
    if (/* some expression */) {
    } else if (/* some other expression */) {
        // and so on... then suddenly: 
        if (/* some other nested expression */) {
            // I forgot that I've allocated other memory at the beginning...
            return A;
        }
    }

    // some miserably written logic here and suddenly
    if (D) delete D; return A;

    // call to some other function with cryptical name without any
    // kind of knowledge what happens with the resource:
    FooTakesReferenceToPointer(&A);

    // suddenly returning something completely different
    // what should I free, A, D...? 
    return C;
}
```

I tried to write in comments what the problems are. Clearly, forget about exceptions. The spaghetti code is so bad that nobody can tell what the logic actually is. Therefore it is really, really easy to forget to free memory and that happens very, very frequently. Solution 1: Throw away and rewrite everything. Solution 2: Keep spaghetti as it is, replace all `new`ed resources by smart pointers and `make_shared` or `make_unique`, let compiler yell. Of course, first write a test suite (which didn't exist before) to guarantee the same (often screwed) behaviour for all possible sets of inputs (which are not documented).

Comment: Yikes!  Execution will never get past the "if (D) delete D; return A;" line.  :^(  (for the record, I think smart pointers are a good idea here)

Comment: Yeah! These "hidden" return statements are easy to overlook and even if you catch it, I often give up on the conditional expression which leads to this branch: if frequently involves several temporary `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`s, ... in conjunction with some weird bit shifting sorcery

Comment: The only solution here is to rewrite it.  When you get such messes, memory leaks are only part of the problem.

Comment: Right, at least in theory. In practice, the code base is so huge and so interwoven that a rewrite is a long, long term task. Memory leaks are one of the first thing which kill you so they need to be treated in short term...

Answer (score 3):

EDIT
As james said this is undefined behaviourso no promises

You could do something like this:

```
#include <vector>

class Base 
{
public:
    Base() 
    {
        baseData = new char [1024];
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        delete [] baseData;
    }


private:
    char* baseData;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        derivedData = new char[1024];
    }

    ~Derived()
    {
        delete [] derivedData;
    }

private:
    char* derivedData;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> datablocks;
    datablocks.push_back(new Base());
    datablocks.push_back(new Derived());

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < datablocks.size(); ++i) 
    {
        delete datablocks[i];
    }
    datablocks.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

The data in the Derived class wont be removed here since we are calling delete on a Base* and the Base class does not declare a virtual destructor.

Comment: That's undefined behavior.  It might leak memory, or it might do anything else.  (In very simple cases like this, you'll likely get a memory leak.  In more complex, real world cases, the program _can_ crash.)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you're processing network data and create polymorphic "message objects" based on the data:

```
while (true)
{
    char buf[1024];

    size_t len = read_from_network(buf, 1024);  // fictitious, for demonstration only

    Message * p = Message::Parse(buf, len);     // allocates new, dynamic, concrete object

    engine.process(p);
}
```

The `engine` object may chose to store the object somewhere and use it again later, and if nobody takes care of deleting it, you have a perfect leak.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers give enough hints, some 'real world' memory leaks which I have seen in our applications.
I don't remember if this was found before or after the release, but, I guess that doesn't matter.

```
void f()
{

   BYTE* b = NULL;

   f = open a file;

   while (!f.end())
   {
      int size = getNextRecordSize(f);
      b = new BYTE;
      readNextRecord(f,b);

      process record;
   }

   delete b;
}
```

Bit hard to detect this. The reviewers might take it for granted that the memory is deleted properly by seeing the delete call. However, it deletes only the memory allocated for the last record. Rest is leaked.

```
class A
{
    public:

    BYTE* get()
    {
        allocate a new buffer, copy the someData buffer and return that. 
        The client is expected to delete it
    };

private:

    BYTE* someData;
};

void f()
{
    A a;
    B.initialize(a.get());  // It is so convenient to use the pointer. It is not obvious from the function name
                           //  that the result of get has to be deleted.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One example I often run across in our code is in image understanding functions, where a temporary 8bit memory is allocated, and never released (yeah, I know, when you do a new, do a delete right afterwards...)

```
unsigned char* dataToBeUsed = new unsigned char[imgsize];
memcpy(dataToBeUsed, original, imgsize);
// use and process the data here

return value;
```

The allocated memory is never released -> memory leak. Windows will kill the memory when the application is exited completely, but before that within the application that memory is just lost -> leaked.

Answer (score 0):

Just lose the pointer to dynamically allocated memory:

```
void foo()
{
   int *arr = new int[100];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A memory leak occurs when the programmer has the memory leak of forgetting to free allocated memory :-)

```
linebuffer = new char[4096];
/* do things */
/* forget to free memory */
```

Normally, if you cause a memory leak and then exit the program, it is not harmful, since the operating system **normally** frees the resources allocated by the program. The problem arises when your application runs for a long period of time (for example, a service). If your program causes memory leaks, then you will run out system's memory, unless the operating system has mechanisms to avoid that; in such case, it will terminate your program.

So, be careful and eat fish: it's very good for memory :-)

Answer (score 0):

To give you a real-world example, a bit of googling turned up [this memory leak](https://www.cert.be/pro/advisories/389-directory-server-normalisation-memory-leak-denial-service) in 389 Directory Server (a RedHat Open Source product).